# How to concatenate two functions into one function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data that is generated:

```
=((E31/320)^2)/(2+(E31/380))
=((E32/320)^2)/(2+(E32/380))
=((E33/320)^2)/(2+(E33/380))
...
```

I want to create a sum of these, but I don't want to just SUM them together; I want to write a function that put these together. I came up with this row:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((ROW(E1:INDEX(E31:E63;C34)))/320)^2/(2 + (E31:E63/380)))
```

The problem with this line is it seems to overdo the whole thing. I need to somehow use one variable for the both `E31:E63` intervals, because it will otherwise loop through the second `E31:E63` n-times, instead of using the same value.

As I see it, there are two solutions.

1. Write the data in columns, but using the first solution
2. Write the function, but try to find something that makes the two `E31:E63` work as one variable.

I want to implement the second option.

Comment: Would named ranges work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((E31:E63/320)^2)/(2+(E31:E63/380)))
```

Will do what you want.

Comment: That did the trick. The problem for me was I did that, but the parentheses were wrong. Thank you for showing me I was on the right track!

Comment: But so to be clear. This SUMPRODUCT function will know that it should use E31 and so on, on both places of the function?

Comment: Yes, FYI, I did a test (with a handful of values) `SUM`ming the separate calculations (as in your sample) and comparing to the `SUMPRODUCT`and the result is the same

Comment: Yes, I had the first solution already calculated. That's how I knew your solution was correct. Thank you again!